# Ошибка при установке PostgreSQL

Tags: windows, postgresql

Возникли проблемы с установкой postgres на windows10. Все советы , что нашел в интернете не сработали : устанавливал 13 и 14 версию, пробовал устанавливать в разные каталоги ,запускать от имени администратора ,смотрел не установлен ли флажок на utf -8 бета версия в языке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Заранее спасибо

Comment: Если ничто не поможет, как крайнее средство можно юзать Постгре в Докере.

Comment: Скачайте новый openServer, там есть postgres, работает отлично

Comment: Попробуй этот дистр: https://www.postgrespro.ru/windows

Comment: Cпасибо, отличные идеи